# I want to write code that surveys my app for specific conditions

Tags: arrays, swift

This is little unoriginal, because i have no code... I'm totally lost here need help. My app is a game, within this game i have an array. When the array is emptied the first round is completed. I need to write code that constantly surveys my array and make a UIalertview once the array.count reaches 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you should use a didSet closure for your array

Eg

```
var array: [AnyObject]! {
    didSet {
        if array.isEmpty {
            //present alert
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally I don't know what is in your array so just set its type to AnyObject

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpfull

Comment: @EricD good point, I'll amend my answer :)

Comment: @Ulrik.S no problem at all! if you are happy with my answer please mark it as correct. It gives me points :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write a custom class that has a `NSMutableArray` property.

In this class you'll have a `setElement:` method, that only with this method you can set one of the objects of the array. Now every time you set one object or delete it (whatever you need) you can inspect it and check if it is empty. :)

Side note, you can keep a reference to the `viewController` that you want to present the `UIalertview` on, and when the time comes use it.